# Circular queue using STL queue?

Tags: c++, stl, queue

I have been searching the internet for a while but can't seem to find an answer on this.

I intend to use stl::queue to conduct some simulation. I am wondering if it is possible to create a circular queue using stl::queue? As far as I know, stl::queue is linear and is not circular by default?

If this is possible, does anyone have any implementation reference that I can refer to?

Thanks.

Comment: Correct, `std::queue` is what it is. But how do you expect your "circular queue" to work, anyway?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is what I am puzzled, whether a circular queue can be implemented using `std::queue`. There are plenty of circular queues in the internet but it does not utilize `std::queue`. From what I know, circular queue reconnects the end of the queue, therefore you will not waste the memory space as the object gets dequeue.

Comment: You could fake it out by using a `std::deque`  and removing the first element every time you add a new item that would push the size past whatever buffer limit has been specified. Not as cheap as a real circular buffer, but dead easy to write.

Comment: Do you mean you want a circular (aka ring) buffer?  Do you know the maximum size ahead of time?  Boost has a circular buffer: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html

Comment: I repeat, no, `std::queue` is what it is. It is not a circular queue and has no means to turn itself into one.

Comment: If your concern is about wasted memory space, you should ask about wasted memory space. For all you know, your assumption that `std::queue` wastes memory space is flawed, and you might be barking up the wrong tree (c.f. [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)). Plus, asking for references (your stated question, but not your real question) is explicitly off-topic here...

Comment: `std::queue` uses whatever container you tell it to, which is `std::deque` by default, but does not have to be. You could use it with an underlying container that _is_ circular.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response so far. Just a small question, does element inside `std::queue` has index and is it accessible?

Answer (score 4):

`std::deque` is defined fairly carefully to be a linear queue. Its design isn't really suitable for a circular queue.

In particular, it breaks the queue up into a number of equal-sized blocks, so if the queue is reasonably balanced (i.e., on average, data is being consumed about as fast as it's being produced) you'll normally have blocks being discarded and ready for re-use, so you can use one for a long time with minimal heap fragmentation.

To accomplish that, a deque (at least normally) uses a two-level storage mechanism. That is to say, it has an expandable array of pointers, each pointing to an equal-sized block that contains the actual data.

For a circular buffer, however, that's pointless and unnecessary. With a circular buffer, you normally allocate a block of memory when you create it, and continue to use that same block of memory until you destroy it. In this case, the two-level storage used by a deque simply adds an extra level of indirection to every access without accomplishing anything useful.

For a circular buffer, you might as well using a single, flat chunk of memory to hold your data, and just create/destroy objects in that block of memory. Here's a simple implementation I wrote some time ago:

```
#ifndef CBUFFER_H_INC
#define CBUFFER_H_INC

template <class T>
class circular_buffer {
    T *data;
    unsigned read_pos;
    unsigned write_pos;
    unsigned in_use;
    const unsigned capacity;
public:
    circular_buffer(unsigned size) :
        data((T *)operator new(size * sizeof(T))),
        read_pos(0),
        write_pos(0),
        in_use(0),
        capacity(size)
    {}

    void push(T const &t) {
        // ensure there's room in buffer:
        if (in_use == capacity) 
            pop();

        // construct copy of object in-place into buffer
        new(&data[write_pos++]) T(t);
        // keep pointer in bounds.
        write_pos %= capacity;
        ++in_use;
    }

    // return oldest object in queue:
    T front() {
        return data[read_pos];
    }

    // remove oldest object from queue:
    void pop() { 
        // destroy the object:
        data[read_pos++].~T();

        // keep pointer in bounds.
        read_pos %= capacity;
        --in_use;
    }
  
~circular_buffer() {
    // first destroy any content
    while (in_use != 0)
        pop();

    // then release the buffer.
    operator delete(data); 
}

};

#endif
```

Comment: std::list would

Answer (score 3):

If you can use The Boost Libraries, there is already a [`boost::circular_buffer`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html) class template that implements the `front()`, `back()`, `push_back()` and `pop_front()` member functions and therefore can be used as the *underlying container* for the [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) container adapter:

```
#include <queue>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <cassert>

template<typename T>
using Queue = std::queue<T, boost::circular_buffer<T>>;

auto main() -> int {
   Queue<int> q(boost::circular_buffer<int>(3)); // capacity of the queue is 3

   q.push(0);
   q.push(1);
   q.push(2);
   assert(q.front() == 0);
   assert(q.back() == 2);

   q.push(3);
   assert(q.front() == 1);
   assert(q.back() == 3);

   q.pop();
   assert(q.front() == 2); 
   assert(q.back() == 3);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `auto main() -> int` is a terrible semantics

Comment: @Quest I just use it to imply that the code was compiled for C++11 at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can found a C++20 implementation of a circular queue at https://github.com/torrentg/cqueue

- Adheres to STL container standards (allocator, iterators, etc)
- Don't require a fixed capacity
- Header-only

Note: I am the project maintainer.